# VB check inside a folder to see if there are files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, http

I am trying to get my vb.net application to look inside a folder on the web server and then let me know whether there are files in there or if the folder is empty...Would anybody know where i would begin? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx)

Comment: hmmm how do i get my application to talk tot he server first i suppose?thanks

Comment: It's the other way around : the server would have to 'talk' to the application. You could use a web-service/webpage that responds to a query : does the path/directory passed exist and does it contain any files.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413344.aspx) method.

```
Dim myDir as DirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathToDir)
If (myDir.EnumerateFiles().Any())) Then
   ' Got files in direcotry!
End If
```

If you are also interested in finding out if there are directories within this one, there is also [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383456.aspx).

Comment: @SLaks - yes, I got that fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is running on the web server, you can simply check whether [`Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/416y61e6.aspx) returns anything.

If your program is running on a client, you'll need to make a server-side script that calls `Directory.GetFileSystemEntries` and returns a value to the client.